# How to debug contract in browser-solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

```
contract users{
struct User{
    uint id;
    string str;
}
User [] public adds;
function del(){
    delete adds;
}
function delElem(uint i){
    delete adds[i];
}
function add(uint id,string cc){
    adds.push(User(id,cc));
}
function getLength()constant returns(uint){
    return adds.length;
}}
```

how to debug this contract in enter link description here, can breakpoint be valid?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22912/debugging-ethereum-contract-by-printing-the-values

Answer (score 5):

There is no Solidity debugger, only an EVM debugger. That is one of the tabs on the right. It allows you to step through the EVM instructions and see the state of memory and storage. To debug solidity code, I suggest you add events instead. For example:

```
contract users{   
event LogThis(uint arg);
struct User{
    uint id;
    string str;
}
User [] public adds;
function del(){
    delete adds;
}
function delElem(uint i){
    delete adds[i];
}
function add(uint id,string cc){
    adds.push(User(id,cc));
}
function getLength()constant returns(uint){
    LogThis(adds.length);
    return adds.length;
}}
```

You will see this event when executing transactions.

Comment: Note that no event will execute if there is any `throw` in the chain of execution. So events are "fair weather friends".