# Debugging Ethereum Contract by printing the values

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, remix

Is there a way that I can print the intermediate result on a console or some log file in order to debug my contract?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you could use events to debug(log) the desired variable.Please read the official [documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events) to get more details.

e.g :

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

    contract test {
        event test_value(uint256 indexed value1);
        uint256 value_test;

        function test_f()  {

            //value_test processing
            test_value(value_test); // log the current value
        }
    }
```

an alternative solution is to use the remix ([browser](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity) solidity) debugger : 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for being the google to my blockchain adventures <3